# UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute Unhandled Exception Duplicate Key: System.Object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unhandled-exception, asp.net-core-middleware

AsP.Net Core `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute()`, I'm redirecting to `/StatusCode/{0}`. I was previously using `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirect()` without any apparant issues but since changing, requests that previously redirected now result in an unhandled exception:

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object

Here's the output from the VS15 debug window:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/guides/some-guide/introdu  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method WebSite.Controllers.GuideController.ReadSection (WebSite) with arguments (some-guide, introdu) - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__permalink_0='?' (Size = 450)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(2) [s].[SectionId], [s].[Description], [s].[DisplayPosition], [s].[DocumentId], [s].[Permalink], [s].[Title], [d].[DocumentId], [d].[CategoryId], [d].[Description], [d].[DisplayPosition], [d].[Permalink], [d].[Subtitle], [d].[Title]
FROM [Sections] AS [s]
INNER JOIN [Documents] AS [d] ON [s].[DocumentId] = [d].[DocumentId]
WHERE [s].[Permalink] = @__permalink_0
ORDER BY [s].[SectionId]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult:Information: Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 404
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action WebSite.Controllers.GuideController.ReadSection (WebSite) in 15.6192ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executing action method WebSite.Controllers.ErrorController.StatusCode (WebSite) with arguments (404) - ModelState is Valid
WebSite.Controllers.ErrorController:Information: Unexpected Status Code: 404, OriginalPath: /guides/some-guide/introdu
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'g4tz3vmn.35h'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewResultExecutor:Information: Executing ViewResult, running view at path /Views/Error/Index.cshtml.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Executed action WebSite.Controllers.ErrorController.StatusCode (WebSite) in 86.9564ms
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\Me\.nuget\packages\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.0\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.1.0\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: System.Object
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowAddingDuplicateWithKeyArgumentException(Object key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore1.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.StatusCodePagesExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Runtime.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 342.116ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
```

It looks like it's executing my StatusCode controller action fine, logging the original path of the error and then bam, I get the exception. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why you’re having that exception.

For testing purposes, I’ve created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application` from within VS 2015.

I’ve selected the `Web Application` template to get the basic stuff already in place.

Inside the `Configure()` method of the `Startup.cs` file, just above the `app.UseStaticFiles();` I’ve added the following:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error2/{0}");
```

I then added the `Error2` ActionResult inside the `HomeController` like so:

```
public IActionResult Error2(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

I created the `Error2.cshtml` view inside the Views--Home folder.

I’ve set a break point on the `return View();` of my `Error2()` method and launched the application in debug.

I navigated to the `About` page (http://localhost:63595/Home/About) successfully, then I purposely added a mistake to trigger a 404 such as: http://localhost:63595/Home/Abouteeee

My break point was hit and the `string id` parameter was holding “404”.

I know this may not answer your question but perhaps taking baby-steps to get things working first, then gradually add stuff may (or not) help you pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: I'm trying to break it down, but I'm struggling to find which dictionary it is referring to. I don't get the error in all instances, only when I am using elements of the path to retrieve database records. With misspelt or non-existent controllers and actions re-execute works as expected in those instances. It is only when querying the database that it causes a problem. Since I have no explicit dictionaries, could it be something to do with EF? I've yet to locate the call that throws the exception.

Comment: While quickly looking thru the entire stack, I noticed the following: An item with the same key has already been added. This error seems related to an INSERT. Since you just mentioned something related to EF, then yes…that might be the reason why you are getting the exception.
Btw…at first glance, the error you seem to be having has nothing to do with the title of your post.

Comment: Thanks Vince, I'll dig into it some more and see what I come up with. I titled the post as is because the error only appeared when I changed from status code pages with redirect to re-execute so I assumed it had something to do with that. Once I've a better handle on the problem I'll rename.

Comment: I'm not too sure if I've narrowed it down or if I'm heading down a rabbit hole. However, I've discovered the exception is thrown if my StatusCode View uses any layout other than `Layout = null;`, if that layout has anything other than `@RenderBody()`. Even so much as `<html>@RenderBody()` causes the exception. I also found that a call to `app.UseWebMarkupMin()` threw the exception regardless of anything else. I've pared everything back so it does nothing but re-execute and it still causes the problem. But what is frustrating is that I can't recreate this in a brand new project. Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, that's not entirely correct. I've narrowed it down to the opening, and only the opening `html`, `head` and `title` tags. If I remove these, then the error is not thrown, I can render a view layout and everything works as expected. I still can't recreate it in a new project. I've removed `WebMarkupMin` in case that was having any impact, but no change. I am thoroughly perplexed.

Answer (score 1):

The stack is difficult to read, because it's async code in a release build, but it doesn't have anything to do with EF. I had to debug with the sources of MVC to track this one down.

It seems to be a bug in the middleware that takes care of saving TempData. The code for that path is different [in the latest version of MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/314aa366e145bb9dd4537404629e6fa2d0a2bae1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/Internal/SaveTempDataFilter.cs#L86).

Here's the interesting part, though: at least for me, the trigger seems to be BrowserLink. So if your Startup.cs contains

```
app.UseBrowserLink();
```

at any point, try commenting that out and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had that same error being thrown when using the error handling:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}")
```

The problem for me was the use of HttpGetAttribute on my error handler action:

```
[HttpGet("/Error/{status}")]
public IActionResult Error(string status) { ..
```

When I changed the attribute to use RouteAttribute instead (ie- to support POST, PUT, etc also), it worked:

```
[Route("/Error/{status}")]
public IActionResult Error(string status) { ..
```

See more...
[GitHub AspNetCore Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9889#issuecomment-489247917)

Comment: omg, this is it, I had the same, wasted so much time looking for a solution. Thank you for finding the time to post it here.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help out...   as so many others on here have done for me over the years!:)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and was not using BrowserLink. But like Rytmis said, it does seem to be caused by TempData. If you're not using TempData anywhere, changing your `AddMvc` call in Startup.cs to the following should fix it:

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
 {
     options.Filters.Remove(new SaveTempDataAttribute());
 });
```

Be careful with that one, it's an ugly hack.

In my case, the root issue turned out to be that the base class my errors controller was inheriting from using the `ControllerBase.HttpContext` property. Once I changed that to get httpContext from IHttpContextAccessor the problem went away.